# passwd: unrecognized option '--stdin' error on Debian when I run my created Bash Script

Tags: bash, debian, passwd

I am using Debian. I am learning Bash scripting. I am creating a script that creates new user and sets password the problem is I get `passwd: unrecognized option '--stdin'` error

That is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Please Enter Your Real Name: " REAL_NAME 
read -p "Please Enter Your User Name: " USER_NAME 
useradd -c "${COMMENT}" -m ${USER_NAME} 
read -p "Please Enter Your Password: " PASSWORD
echo ${PASSWORD} | passwd --stdin ${USER_NAME}
passwd -e ${USER_NAME}
```

Comment: Maybe there is no such option.

Comment: What is the replacement of this option?

Comment: `echo -e "$PASSWORD\n$PASSWORD" | passwd "$USER_NAME"`

Comment: @Cyrus Thanks a lot this worked

Answer (score 6):

As tested on Debian 10 @ Docker image

```
echo -e "badpass\nbadpass" | passwd urname
```

This will work in /bin/bash, not in /bin/sh

---

```
echo "urname:badpass" | chpasswd
```

This will work in /bin/sh and /bin/bash

Answer (score 3):

There is no `--stdin` option, and you need to protect your variable with quotes.

This is a working version:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Please Enter Your Real Name: " REAL_NAME 
read -p "Please Enter Your User Name: " USER_NAME 
useradd -c "${COMMENT}" -m ${USER_NAME} 
read -p "Please Enter Your Password: " PASSWORD
echo -e "$PASSWORD\n$PASSWORD" |passwd "$USER_NAME"
passwd -e ${USER_NAME}
```